# How to move a virtual PC 's image (Windows Virtual PC) to a new location in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, file-transfer, microsoft-virtual-pc

I tried to move the image files of my virtual pc to a new folder location but I cannot do it. The system keeps saying the file .vcm is being used by the Virual PC Host Process. The other files can be moved though.

If you have a work-around for this, please help!

Comment: You've got Virtual PC completely turned off, correct? No running VMs anywhere on the PC at all.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options if anything you're trying to move/modify is reporting it's 'in use'.

In order of ease/obviousness:

- Reboot
- Determine what has a file handle on it exactly and close the handle (see below*).
- [Boot into Safe-Mode](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/force-windows-to-boot-into-safe-mode-without-using-the-f8-key/)
- Boot into a live boot operating system like [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) and move the file there

*To detect a file handle use a tool like [Process Explorer from Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)
 - Use Find > Find Handle or DLL (try a few search terms even file path)
 - If found right click on the bottom window entry for the 'handle'
 - Select 'Close Handle'